# UWP Currency Formatter force to use symbol $ instead of USD

Tags: uwp, currency, currency-formatting

I am using next code (C++/CX):

```
using namespace Windows::Globalization::NumberFormatting;
CurrencyFormatter^ currencyFormatter = ref new CurrencyFormatter(Windows::Globalization::CurrencyIdentifiers::USD);
currencyFormatter->IsGrouped = true;
currencyFormatter->IsDecimalPointAlwaysDisplayed = true;
currencyFormatter->Mode = CurrencyFormatterMode::UseSymbol;
```

The displayed text is **USD 148,842.50**

I want to display **$ 148,842.50** instead, using **$** symbol instead of **USD** code.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use converter as shown below
Xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding YourPropertyName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
Converter={StaticResource DecimalToCurrencyConverter} }"
```

Converter Code

```
 public class DecimalToCurrencyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language )
        {
            if( value == null )
                return null;
            else
                return String.Format( "{0:C2}", value );
        }

        public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language )
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```